# Calculating Turn Times Between Two Dates in TSQL

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I'm using the below code to calculate a Turn Time between two dates in my SQL.

Now I want to exclude Weekends in this calculation.. What would be the easiest way for me to accomplish this?

```
 avg(DATEDIFF(hh, b.startenda, b.enddate))/24
```

Comment: What do you want to do when either b.startenda or b.endate are a weekend day? Skip over them, convert them to the nearest weekday, or something else?

Comment: B.startenda and b.enddate will never fall on a weekend. Only work Weekdays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/6ac4543f-22b5-419f-87db-ea747ec80500/datediff-calculating-working-days

This walks you through creating a calendar table and a stored procedure for getting the number of working days between two dates.